# Manga about a noble's daughter, possibly an isekai

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The manga had only a few chapters currently translated to English when I first read it. That was earlier this year, so I assume it still has little translated chapters.

The setting is one of those medieval-looking settings in a world with swords (and probably magic too. Don't remember that for sure).

High chance it's an isekai manga, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

The main character is the daughter of some noble family. I remember her having light-colored hair.

In one of the first chapters, she beats someone else in a swordfight with relative ease.

At the moment, I can't recall much else. I will answer any questions if I'm able to.

Edit: I know for a fact that it was a manga. Not a manhwa or a manhua.

Comment: Do you have particular manga sites you frequent? Could in be a *manhua* (Korean) instead? Were all of the characters caucasian? Darker-skinned? Human? Elven? :) What sort of drawing style?

Comment: I use kissmanga, usually. I'm sure it was a manga, not a manhwa or manhua. There were no darker-skinned or non-human characters in the first few chapters as far as I remember. I don't recall very much about the drawing style. And could you maybe clarify what exactly 'caucasian' means? I'm not a native English speaker, you see

Comment: Ah. Caucasian is basically "white". Can I have you visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question? It's got some more details you might be able to try to answer to improve your question.

Comment: I Belong to House Castielo (https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-belong-to-house-castielo) is also a manhwa as is Who Made Me a Princess? (https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/who-made-me-a-princess)

Comment: Ah, in that case, as far as I can remember, all of the characters were caucasian. I also visited that link, but I'm sorry to say that I unfortunately really don't recall much else from the manga at the moment. As for the two manhwa you suggested, those were both not it. I am sure it was a manga.

Comment: I have some questions that might help narrow things down if you can answer them.  When she won the sword fight, was she using a sword, or did she just beat up someone who was attacking her with a sword? How violent was this fight, did it end up with the loser disarmed, or was this more the loser is severely injured?  Was this at an academy, in a town, in a forest? Since you aren't certain its an isekai you might not be able to answer this, but do you remember if it was a guy or a girl who became the noble's daughter?

Comment: She was wielding a sword in the fight. The fight wasn't all too violent, since I'm pretty sure it was more like a duel. I think nobody even got wounded. I don't recall where exactly the fight took place, but I do recall it being outside, and do know that it was not in a forest. And as you guessed, I can't answer the last question. I've read tons of isekai and stories with similar settings, so I tend to forget how a main character exactly ended up in their situation at the start of a story

Answer (score 3):

[image: Front cover of It Seems My Body is Completely Invincible]

Could you be thinking of *It Seems My Body is Completely Invincible*? It’s an isekai manga that only had 4 chapters translated up until a couple months ago. The protagonist is the daughter of a duke and easily beats the child of her sword instructor in a mock fight in the first few chapters.

Comment: Looking over the first few chapters, it seems that the instructor was for martial arts, at least in the translations i found, and the mock fight was also using martial arts.  It does look closer to OP's description than anything else i have found though.

Answer (score 1):

[I Will Go and Disappear Obediently](https://mangadex.org/title/42090/i-will-go-and-disappear-obediently) looks like a possibility.

The main character's hair seems to be white. She is the daughter of the king's protector and is called princess in the first chapters.  The manga is only a few chapters long, and was only 2-3 chapters long at the beginning of the year.

While i don't see a duel or fight that is easily won, there is a scene that has end of training for the day with the instructor saying the Main Character will beat him before long. She is being trained to protect the prince when she is older, like her father protects the king. The prince calls her his 'sword' and there are a few other mentions of her family being the King's "Sword".

Comment: That's not the one. Though, thank you for trying to help nontheless!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe *금발의 정령사*, aka [*The Goldenhaired Elementalist*](https://365manga.com/manga/the-golden-haired-elementalist/)?

[image: Front cover of *The Goldenhaired Elementalist*]

> I thought I was dead, but when I woke up, I was reincarnated as a nobleman’s daughter?! The only thing I did in the seventeen years of my first life was studying. Now that I’m alive again, I won’t live just to study! The second life of an ordinary middle school girl with a slightly strange personality, Jean, begins an unstoppable journey on this continent!

Found with a search for `manga "nobleman's daughter"`. Just started being translated in January 2020. No swordfight yet in the first two chapters, though.

Comment: That's not the one. Thanks for the attempted answer, though. I know that it was a manga, not a manhwa or a manhua. Maybe that bit of information can help